# Default buttons are shown using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am outputting the next line after AJAX query once the document is ready.

```
<div id = "log_in"><button name = "log_in" class = "btn btn-link" type = "button">Prijaviti se</button></div>
```

The next lines are included into the head of the ready document

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
<link href="twitter-bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="twitter-bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

The output is a button may be created by default. Once it's clicked the border gets blue.
I used most of classes for button from 
http://bootstrap-ru.com/base_css.php#buttons
but no result.
Solutions?

Comment: A tool like Firebug is great help in these situations. First you can check that the css'es are loaded correctly, secondly you can see exactly what rules is styling what element.

Comment: Button works if you add it without the ajax call?

Comment: You'll probably need to show a demo or a live site to get better help with this. It sounds like a rather unique situation.

Comment: I solved this using Firebug.